# Annoying slow responsiveness of form whilst populating combos on background thread

Tags: winforms, data-binding

I have a form with 2 tabs.  The first tab is boring, the second tab (unseen as default to the user) contains many comboboxes.

Using the FormLoad() event I populate a combobox on the second tab (with around 11,000 items/strings) on a background thread. The sql command to do this is also asynchronous.

Now, in theory this should mean that when the user finally gets round to clicking the second tab (whether that be in 10 seconds or 10 hours) they should be instantly presented with a nicely populated control - but there is ALWAYS a 4 second delay.  I just don't get it!  If all the heavy lifting is done via the background thread (the whole reason for using them in the first place!), why the heck is my application still slow and unresponsive when the user clicks that darn second tab??!!?!

*Bearing in mind you have to give the application a chance to fill the combo in the first place, plus I know when it's finished populating as the backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerComplete() method fires and sends a debug message to tell me all work has finished.*

Any help will be much appreciated....

Comment: Question: if you start your background thread on-demand (with a button on the first tab, for example) and before start it you show 2nd tab once you get the same results?

Comment: 11,000 items in a combo ain't ever going to be nice. A better adjective would be unusable. While I'll admit to some curiosity as to the issue, I'd be working on the real problem if I was you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11,000 is a lot! The work has been done to populate the comboBox items on the background thread, but the form still has to show all those items. This means the UI thread has to render a proportion of them (or all of them) to the UI (into memory) ready for scrolling; this is what is taking time.

I would suggest overriding the `ComboBox` control and handling the scroll event yourself. This way you can load a subset of the entire list sequentially when you need them (if that is possible in your case). This will prevent the four second delay you speak of.

Comment: 11K is too much you are right (and others too) - in fact is ridiculous - it's obvious now that this needs autocomplete - of course this depends on the user having a good idea what to search for before hand.

Comment: Yeah. The autocomplete might be a headache to do as well. Check [The CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com) as I am sure there are more articles (more suitable for what you want) [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16285/Auto-Complete-ComboBox). All the best...